# Vote to close: Belongs on ...

Tags: feature-request

We've got "Vote to Close: Belongs on Meta", shouldn't we also have:

Vote to Close:

- Belongs on StackOverflow
- Belongs on ServerFault

Because of the potential crossover, don't we risk muddling the communities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes -- but this ability won't be "unlocked" until the site proves itself viable in the public beta.

Answer (score 3):

It won't muddle the communities if clear lines are drawn. Unfortunately, the lines are already muddy because we have tons of open questions that belong SO, SF, and SU but haven't been moved.

Answer (score 1):

[This has an official answer from Jeff himself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan/54524#54524):

> ... this will be possible.
>
> The trick here is that we'll only
>   "unlock" question migration paths
>   between sites that have an some kind
>   of rational relationship, so the odds
>   of that off-topic (but on-topic for
>   the other network site) question being
>   asked has some actual chance of
>   occuring in the real world.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> "what if someone asks a gardening question on Stack Overflow?"
> ```
>
> ... is incredibly unlikely to happen.